# Shadow on a NavigationBar with iOS5 (Monotouch or ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, ios5, shadow

I'm looking forward to add a shadow on a NavigationBar in iOS5... For now, I'm using

```
m_navigationController.NavigationBar.Layer.ShadowColor   =  UIColor.Black.CGColor;
m_navigationController.NavigationBar.Layer.ShadowOffset  =  new System.Drawing.SizeF( 1f, 1f );
m_navigationController.NavigationBar.Layer.ShadowRadius  =  3f;
m_navigationController.NavigationBar.Layer.ShadowOpacity =  1f;
```

This is C# but well, it works in Obj-C as well. However, this method does not longer work in iOS5, does anybody know how to get it work?

Comment: is this a new project? or an old project that stopped working as intended when iOS 5 came out? If it's a new one, make sure you've linked QuartzCore.

Comment: New project, however, this method doesn't longer work in iOS5. Same thing to add a custom background, I had to use a new method added in iOS5.

Comment: Define "does not longer work." Does it simply do nothing, do you get an error message, something else maybe?

Comment: No system exception, no crash. It just doesnt longer affect the NavigationBar.

Comment: It still works on iOS4 tho. All references to "m_navigationController.NavigationBar.Layer." seems to no longer work in iOS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
m_navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor   =  [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
m_navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset  =  CGSizeMake( 1.0, 1.0 );
m_navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius  =  3.0;
m_navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity =  1.0;
```

That's Objective-C code.  Make sure you `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` at the top of your file.

Comment: The above code seems to be an objective-c translation of the original C# code. Was that really an answer? i.e. does that works differently (than MonoTouch) on iOS 5 ?!? and the same as iOS4 ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with MonoTouch, but I figured that it probably wasn't compatible with iOS 5.  So I offered an Objective-C "translation."

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code no longer works is that in iOS 5 a new styling system was introduced.   So you use the UIAppearance system instead.

This describes how the new UIAppearance system works with MonoTouch:

http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Oct-14.html

The class UIAppearance:

http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIAppearance

The UINavigationBar property for Appearance:
http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIProgressView.Appearance

The set of properties you can set on the UINavigationBar's Appearance property:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UIProgressView.Appearance